# Why is it not possible to declare a static or constant std::path::Path object in Rust?

Tags: rust, path, static, constants

I am working on a CLI for learning purposes. This CLI involves a filesystem and I'd like to declare some public and static (or constant) Path objects in a "filesystem" module so that other modules in the crate can use them when needed.

I am unable to declare those in a way that satisfies my pedantry. I know it is achievable with some lazy evaluation technique but that would store the data on the heap ... given the paths are known at compile time I simply do not understand why we cannot store it as a static or constant value.

I do understand that the [Path::new method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.new) should be defined with `pub **const** fn new()` for this to work, but given [that is not the case](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/path.rs.html#2037) and the compiler recommends using `Lazy::new(|| ...)`, I imagine there is a reason even though the path is hard coded, it cannot be evaluated at compile time using static or const ...

Please note that I am not looking for workarounds that involve storing the path as a string or on the heap, but rather, a way to achieve what I want or an explanation on why it is not achievable.

Below is a snippet to better illustrate what I am trying to achieve, associated with the compiler error :

```
use std::path::Path;

static ROOT_DIR: &Path = Path::new("/myproject");
// static LOGS_DIR: &Path = ROOT_DIR.join("logs").as_path();


fn main() {
    println!("{}", ROOT_DIR.display());
    // println!("{}", LOGS_DIR.display());
}
```

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `Path::new::<str>` in statics
 --> src/main.rs:4:26
  |
4 | static ROOT_DIR: &Path = Path::new("/myproject");
  |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
  = note: consider wrapping this expression in `Lazy::new(|| ...)` from the `once_cell` crate: https://crates.io/crates/once_cell

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0015`.
error: could not compile `shaka` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible currently, even on nightly.

The reason is because [`Path::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.new) is defined as a generic method. `Path::new(str)` is just another way of saying `str.as_ref().as_ref()` (invoking [`AsRef::as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html), first to convert to `OsStr` (`impl AsRef<OsStr> for str`) then to convert this to `Path` (`impl AsRef<Path> for OsStr`), just more clear and better fit for inference. `Path::new()` accepts everything that implements `AsRef<OsStr>`.

To constify this, we would have to constify the `AsRef` implementation and constrain `AsRef` to be `const`. [And this is only possible on nightly currently](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67792), with major design questions. So there is no way we cannot make `Path::new()` const on stable.

[There is an opened PR for adding methods that can do that const-way](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/92930), but it is not merged and it is not clear whether we want to commit to this workaround.

Answer (score -1):

If you really, really want to do this, it's possible with `unsafe` code.

```rust
use std::path::Path;

const ROOT_DIR: &Path = {
    let s = "/myproject";
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(s.as_bytes()) }
};

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", ROOT_DIR);
}
```

Comment: This is unsound. The layout of `Path` is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is it not just an `OsStr`, which is in turn a sequence of bytes?

Comment: Nothing of this is specified. Not that `&Path` is just `&OsStr`, and not what `OsStr` is.